# regular expression in matching partially correct keyword

Tags: python, regex

I want to match strings to keywords. The keywords may not be exactly matched and the maximum unmatched characters is set to 2.

How to use regular expression to do it?

Thanks.

Here are examples:

```
string                     partially matched 'abc technology.com'?
apc technology.om                       yes(wrong p and miss c)
abctechnologycom                        yes(miss space and dot)
abc technolog.con                       yes(miss y and wrong n)
abtechnology.com                        yes(miss c and space)
abc technology.c                        yes(miss o and m)
abtechnology.co                         no(miss c, space and m)
abc technology.                         no(miss com)
abctechnology.c                         no(mis space and om)
```

Comment: Don't use regexes for something that is not a *regular expression* or expressible as a finite automata. Consider looking into string distance (metric distance).

Comment: Would string distance functions be of any help to you?

Comment: @mroman, how to use string distance function?

Comment: @John well.. there are multiple such functions with different properties. The most known is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance 
You might benefit from reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching

Comment: Thank you, mroman. What about searching partially matched keyword from a long string? For example, string = 'Last night I went to abc technolgy.co and bought a  head-phone. It was very cheap but ......'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) library and work with fuzzy matching (which is fitting your use-case), specifying a maximum of mismatches, like:

```
import regex
from pprint import pprint

matcher = regex.compile(r'(abc technology\.com){e<3}')

tests = [
  "apc technology.om",
  "abctechnologycom",
  "abc technolog.con",
  "abtechnology.com",
  "abc technology.c",
  "abtechnology.co",
  "abc technology.",
  "abctechnology.c",
]

for test in tests:
  pprint(matcher.match(test))
```

[Online demo here](https://repl.it/repls/KindheartedCrushingBusinesses)

When the error count is hit, it will return `None`, otherwise an object that contains a `fuzzy_counts` tuple, which gives you the total number of substitutions, insertions, deletions. It also contains a `fuzzy_changes` tuple, which contains the positions of each substitution, insertion, deletion done.

Comment: Great. Your answer is very good. Thank you very much. wiesion.

Comment: yw! There are many more options for fuzzy matching, if you go through the pypi page of regex you will learn more about it (what sub. ins. del. means etc).

Comment: How to apply your regex method in pandas? For example, `df['string'].str.contains(r'(abc technology\.com){e<3}')` does not work. It will be slow when using `apply`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how much data are you trying to handle and how long does `df['string'].apply(matcher.match)` take? And did you try to `df['string'].str.contains(matcher.match)`? Because internally pandas is using the `re` module, not the `regex`.

Comment: Do you mean `matcher = re.compile(r'(abc technology\.com){e<3}')' and `df['string'].str.contains(matcher.match)`? It doesn't work. I am going to match 25,000 records. Each matches 3 keywords.

Comment: How to write the expression using re?

Comment: The native `re` module does not support Levenshtein distance - also i am not that familiar with pandas, but i think there is a way to pass the column names to apply so that it doesn't apply it to all columns

Comment: Could you figure it out how to pass the function to single columns?